# Tcpdf Hindi sentence display issue

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, tcpdf, hindi

I am trying to create pdf file using tcpdf library in PHP Programming language. trying from yesterday but still getting `????????` instead of Hindi fonts. 
I am trying to display this sentence :

> प्रविष्टि कर कुल बिक्री मूल्य वेट के साथ
>   भार(ग्रा) टिन मात्रा(सं) भुगतान का प्रकार विवरण जारीकर्ता कार्ड

I have included 2 to 3 different Hindi fonts but getting only question marks only. If you have good example with Hindi language in tcpdf or mpdf please guide me how to do it. I have also used to set UTF-8, iso-8859-1 standard in PHP file but not any luck. You can refer my code below:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
//header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252');


// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 007', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
//TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/Devanagari/Devanagari.ttf', 'TrueType', "", 32);
//TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('../fonts/Agra.svg', 'TrueTypeUnicode', "", 32);
// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('krutidev021', '', 14, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print
$html = "प्रविष्टि कर कुल बिक्री मूल्य वेट के साथ
भार(ग्रा) टिन मात्रा(सं) भुगतान का प्रकार विवरण जारीकर्ता कार्ड";

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', utf8_encode($html), 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

// ---------------------------------------------------------


$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Answer (score 4):

**freesans,freesansb,freeserif,freeserifb** fonts have hindi language support, these fonts are in tcpdf font folder.So set font `$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);`

Full Code

```
<?php
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 018');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 018', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language dependent data:
$lg = Array();
$l['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$l['a_meta_dir'] = 'ltr';
$l['a_meta_language'] = 'hi';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Hindi content
$htmlhindi = 'नमस्ते आप कैसे हैं';
$pdf->WriteHTML($htmlhindi, true, 0, true, 0);



// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_018.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Comment: Hi this is tested code and is working good. have you followed instruction _freesans,freesansb,freeserif,freeserifb fonts have hindi language support, these fonts are in tcpdf font folder.So set font $pdf->SetFont('freesans', '', 12);_

Comment: Yes I have followed your instruction. There is problem with Namaste world.

Comment: Sorry for my typo. I have executed your code without changing anything and I found there is problem with first word.

Comment: I Know its an old thread but I am stuck on same issue. Hindi text is able to display but it is not properly displaying. the words are splitting and forming individual characters instead of being one whole character.

Comment: Hi @Deep 3015. I tried this code, but its not working. Namaste word is not well formed. I even tried the hindi string that dhavald99 has posted in question. It doesnt work either.

Comment: Is TCPDF supports all the languages? If yes, kindly suggest how did you solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: its not working perfectly, generating many incorrect words