# how support hindi font in tFPDF

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin name pafe its uses tFPDF. but it is not supported Hindi yet. how can I edit to get Hindi font also?

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php

Comment: currently, pdf show boxes when I use Hindi text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41918435/8719734

Comment: tcpdf structure is diffrent from tfpdf